# Create new dataset with each iteration of loop

Tags: r, loops

I have `nums` defined to be an integer vector of 50 different random numbers between 1 and 50

```
nums = sample(50, replace=TRUE)
```

I am trying to create a graph that would show how the mean and median are impacted when just one particular value, `nums[1]` henceforth, is changed to take on a whole host of values between  -97 and 99, which are both 98 integers away from 1.

What I would like is to create 100 datasets, where `nums[1]` is different in each one. I am using a for loop to increment `nums[1]` by 2 each time, which will mean 100 iterations will bring `nums[1]` up to 99.

```
nums[[1]] = -97
for(i in 1:100) {
  nums[[1]] = (nums[[1]] + 2)
}
```

How can I create a new dataset with the current value of `nums[1]` plus all the other values in `nums` unchanged? This is trickier than it seems, because I would then like to be able to loop through those datasets and display the mean and median for each. For example, I can call `mean(nums)` to display the mean for this.

But that would mean I need a predictable naming scheme so I can loop back through them. Is that even possible? I was thinking of doing something like "create new dataset named" `nums[i]` except `[]` is used for indexes within the array so I'm not sure how I would do that.

From there, I think I could add `nums[1]` and then `nums[2:50]` to the dataset, but I'm stuck on how to actually create the individual sets.

**EDIT:**

```
sets <- lapply(seq(-97, 99, by = 2), function(x) {
    nums[1] = x
    print(nums)
})
for(i in 1:99) {
  x1value = sets[i[1]]
  mean = mean(sets[i])
  median = median(sets[i])
}
```

Using lapply, I can add the following for loop below to get the value of x[1] for each dataset, and the mean and median for each dataset. How would I then do the same thing and put each of these values in a row of new data frame that can be used by ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
set.seed(2017)
nums <- sample(50, replace=TRUE)

lst <- lapply(seq(-97, 99, by = 2), function(x) { nums[1] <- x; nums; })
```

or using `replace`

```
lst <- lapply(seq(-97, 99, by = 2), function(x) replace(nums, 1, x))
```

Both methods return a `list` of `integer` `vectors` where the first element of every `vector` has been replaced by a value `seq(-97, 99, by = 2)`. We end up with `length(seq(-97, 99, by = 2)) = 99` elements in the `list`.

*"I have `nums` defined to be a list (array) of 50 different random numbers [...]"* Please note that `nums` is an `integer` `vector` (not a `list` nor an `array`).